# Select a tag nested in layers of divs

Tags: html, css, wordpress

all!

I am having a problem with selecting the `<p>`s separately from each other. I want to style the first `<p class="a">` differently than the second `<p class="a">`.

It would be much easier (and wouldn't need to be asked here) to assign a class/id to those `<p>`s but I cannot do that because I am using a WordPress theme.

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div>
        <div>
            <div>
                <p class="a"></p>
                <p class="b"></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div>
            <div>
                <p class="a"></p>
                <p class="b"></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this:

```css
.wrapper > div:first-child p.a {
  color:red;
}
.wrapper > div:last-child p.a {
  color:blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div>
        <div>
            <div>
                <p class="a">aa</p>
                <p class="b">bb</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div>
            <div>
                <p class="a">aa</p>
                <p class="b">bb</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just select it with nth-of-type and the direct descendant selector.

nth-child works too if this is the exact structure and not any different element besides `<p>` in that `<div>`

```css
.wrapper > div:first-of-type p.a {
  color:blue;
}
.wrapper > div:nth-of-type(2) p.a {
  color:pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div>
        <div>
            <div>
                <p class="a">aa</p>
                <p class="b">bb</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div>
            <div>
                <p class="a">aa</p>
                <p class="b">bb</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```